# Download slack file with files:read not working?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I'm building a slack bot to download images posted in its channels. Both the user and bot in my application have files:read permissions. However, when my bearer token is the bot's oauth token, I can't download the file. When my bearer token is the user's bearer token, I can. Anybody know why?

Comment: Are you getting any errors when you try to download the file with the bot token?

Comment: From personal experience, Slack will still let you download the file, it will just be corrupted when you open it :/. My questions are, 1. Have you ensured that your app has been reinstalled and token scopes are up to date? 2. There are multiple download links for Slack files, which one are you using?